# How to Compare Two SQL Files in Shell Script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix

I have two SQL files A.sql and B.sql. My requirement is I have to compare A.sql and B.sql and I need to check query which are present in A.sql is present in B.sql or not, if it is not there in B.sql then we need to move Query from A.sql to newfile.sql which is not present in B.sql

***Below is the Example***

***A.sql***

```
Select * from emp;
Select * from dept;
Select * from student;
Select * from subject;
```

***B.sql***

```
Select * from emp;
Select * from dept;
```

***Output Excepted***

```
Select * from student;
Select * from subject;
```

***Output what I am getting***

```
Select * from dept;
Select * from student;
Select * from subject;
```

***Below is my script***

```
while read -rd ';' i_sql
  do
     flag=0
     while read -rd ';' e_sql
     do
       if [ "$i_sql" != "$e_sql" ];
       then
           flag=0
       else 
           flag=1
           break
       fi
     done < B.sql
     if [ !$flag ]
     then
         echo "$i_sql">>newfile.sql
   fi
 done < A.sql
```

Reading the sql query upto semicolon from A.sql and storing it in i_sql

```
while read -rd ';' i_sql
```

Reading the sql query upto semicolon from B.sql and storing it in e_sql

```
while read -rd ';' e_sql
```

Below i am comparing the i_sql and e_sql if it is equal i am going to else part using break so that it
should not compare with other statements.If it is not equal i am setting flag=0, later i am moving the
query which is not present in B.sql to newfile.sql outside the inner while loop.

```
 if [ "$i_sql" != "$e_sql" ];
       then
           flag=0
       else
           flag=1
           break
        fi
    done < B.sql
```

Below i am moving the Sql query to newfile.sql which is not there in B.sql and which is present in A.sql.

```
if [ !$flag ]
 then
     echo "$i_sql">>newfile.sql
 fi
 done < A.sql
```

Can anyone please help with the above issue and let me know what is wrong.

**Note : My one SQL query doesn't occupies single line, it will be more than 4-5 lines. Just for an example I have used a single line query.**

**Since my one SQL query is having more than 4-5 lines, so I am reading SQL query in while loop upto semicolon and storing it in a variable and then I am using the variable for comparison.**

***Thanks in advance!!!***

Comment: Have you tried using the `diff` program?

Comment: yes we tried `diff B.sql A.sql > C.sql`, but it was not working

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in your input files one query occupies exactly one line. You did not say this explicitly, but your example suggests it. In this case, you could interpret B.sql a list of *literal pattern* and ask `grep`, which of these pattern do not occur in A.sql :

```
grep -F -f B.sql -v A.sql
```

`-F` says *literal pattern*, `-f` tells grep where to look for the pattern, and `-v` says to report lines where none of the pattern matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems correct. But you need to take care of more details like casing difference, difference in white spaces between the words (Let's say same query has a space before semicolon in one file and no space in the other.)

The reason why 'Select * from dept;' appears in the result may be some whitespace difference.

As suggested in the comments, it is better to use a diff tool command line instead of writing the logic yourself. You can explore diff / vimdiff / git diff ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { map[$0]=1 } FNR!=NR && map[$0]!=1 { print $0>> "newfile.sql";close("newfile.sql") } FNR!=NR && map[$0]==1 { print }'  B.sql A.sql > A.sql.tmp
```

Process B.sql first (NR==FNR). Create a array indexed with the entries. When we process A.sql (FNR!=NR) and there is not an entry in the map array. we print the line to a newfile.sql file. Otherwise we print to screen.

You can then commit the output on screen back to the A.sql file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { map[$0]=1 } FNR!=NR && map[$0]!=1 { print $0>> "newfile.sql";close("newfile.sql") } FNR!=NR && map[$0]==1 { print }'  B.sql A.sql > A.sql.tmp > A.sql.tmp && mv -f A.sql.tmp A.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line :

```
if [ !$flag ]
```

which always yields `true` beacuse `!1` and `!0` are non-empty strings.

What you need is :

```
if [ $flag = 0 ]
```